# Log alarm to file, but only on alarm state transition from off to on

Tags: qt

There is a Master-slave communication. During the communication, in every 100 ms slave gets data.for every on(1) and off(0) are received .. if alarm on indication comes i.e. slave.. gets 1... that 1 is continuously coming , consequently Alarm window appears, when user closes the window, that means alarm is acknowledged.

My requirement is , whenever alarm on(1) comes, that is to be recorded in a file, i am able to do it,it works fine. since Master sends 1 continuously until user acknowledges the alarm.So 1(alarm notification is recorded multiple times in file)). But i need file should record one time until the other type of alarm comes. There are several type of alarm.
It might be more then one alarm. But one alarm should be recorded once if its not acknowledged.

Comment: can't you simply have a previous state indicator for each alarm, and only log to a file when an alarm is ON AND its previous state was OFF?

Comment: thanx for your quick response... actually same state is coming in 100 ms until the  user acknowledges

Comment: so you have a state variable for each alarm. Every 100ms you get a state update, see if the state has changed, and log if it has. Is there a reason that won't work (100ms is a LONG time for a computer)

Comment: can we have discussion on phone.. if u dont mind,plz share ur no.

Comment: `every on(1) and off(0) are received`, `until the other type of alarm comes` - What you know type of alarm?

Comment: when alarm comes.. 1 is rcvd  and when user acknowledges then it bcms 0.. there are multiple type of alarms...  for each alarm status e.g. 1(on) and off(0) rcvd